# Service connection error with sonatype nexus connection in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, nexus3, serviceconnection

I am using a generic service connection for sonatype nexus repository in Azure Devops but I'm getting an error

> HttpResponse.statusCode: 404, HttpResponse.statusMessage: Repository not found

[image]

I can upload artifacts using curl command and have valid access to the repository. I tried different urls and options but no luck.

Full error:

> Upload failed, HttpResponse.statusCode: 404, HttpResponse.statusMessage: Repository not found
>
> ##[error] Upload failed, HttpResponse.statusCode: 404, HttpResponse.statusMessage: Repository not found
>
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Upload failed, HttpResponse.statusCode: 404, HttpResponse.statusMessage: Repository not found
>
> ##[debug]task result: Failed
> ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Upload failed, HttpResponse.statusCode: 404, HttpResponse.statusMessage: Repository not found
> Finishing: nexusArtifactUpload

Logs: nexusUploadUrl=https://nexus-xxx-org/nexus/repository/ **service/local/artifact/maven/content**

Above URL is wrong, any idea how can I update service/local/artifact/maven/content? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need to remove /nexus/repository from your service connections server url

Comment: No, I got the same 404 error without /nexus/repository as well.  ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Upload failed, HttpResponse.statusCode: 404, HttpResponse.statusMessage: Not Found
Finishing: nexusArtifactUpload